# Retrieve past results

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to retrieve previous results in the command window? For example i had some matrices and vectors in the command window and after an error the matlab was closed . Is it possible to retrieve them?

Thanks

Comment: your best bet is to use the command history and just rerun everything you did for that session... probably leave out that last line that caused the error though

Comment: Yes but does matlab have any kind of memory that saves some previous results or something like that?

Comment: Not that I know of but that doesn't matter because it save every command you type so you can literally rerun exactly what you did in the session that crashed thus recreating the last state from the opening state.

Comment: Unless you are relying on external data that you edited during the session? In which case I don't think there is much you can do unless you can restore those data externally.

Answer (score -1):

No guarantees about what happens after a crash, but in general,  use the command `diary('filename.txt')`  to append all text in the `CommandWindow`  -- **not** the `Command History` window -- to that text file.

(I dunno why MathWorks doesn't call the "CommandWindow" what it is, i.e. the Console, but there you are.)